# How to connect to Oracle hyperion (HFM) using Python?

Tags: python, oracle, hyperion

It is possible to connect to HFM (The Cube, not the database) using python instead of Oracle SmartView Plugin in Excel? How can I do it to do a retrieve/extraction?

Regards,

Comment: afaik HFM is a relational database, not a cube. If Essbase cube is what you have in mind then consider using https://github.com/jasonwjones/essbasepy module. Regards, Marcel

Comment: Thanks, Sorry that I said incorrectly, 

I thought all the time that ESSBASE is a database and HFM has an OLAP module because where I am working there are two different instances one is called locally as HFM where I am using Smartview throught Excel to connect to a cube and another called locally as ESSBASE where I can connected using a different connector through Excel but where is the Budget data or precook Actual not official like the HFM are It is official and closed. I will check the link, thanks a lot. 

If you can help me to clarify more about the differences I will appreciate.

Comment: @Cristian Saavedra Desmoineaux did you find a solution to this? I'm recently interacting with SmartView Plugin in Excel and am wondering if I can just externally query the data using python by calling multiple instances of the excel plugin and sending various queries - effectively creating a mock-asynchronous call - then pulling the returns back from the excel sheets to transform as desired.

Comment: Hi @JamesAndrewBush, I didn't find a direct connection with Python to HFM (OLAP Cube), but as a shortcut, I created a visual basic script Excel Macro that runs all the steps like connection, refresh, and save the file then from then I manipulated using Python Pandas. The ESSBASEPY works if you have replicated the ESSBASE database as the HFM, not my case.